# How do i get ApplicationController?

Tags: ember.js

How can I get an ApplicationController inside my HomeController?

```
 HomeController=Ember.Controller.Extend({
   init:function {
        // Here I want to get My application controller. Is there any way to get??
   }

 })
```

Comment: Use "controllerFor" to get the controllers....    this.controllerFor('application')  should work

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> How can I get an ApplicationController inside my HomeController?

To specify dependencies (or needs) between controllers, use the `needs` property:

```
HomeController=Ember.Controller.Extend({
  needs: ['application']
})
```

Now Ember will make the application controller accessible from inside your HomeController as `controllers.application`. You can use it like any other `HomeController`, it is even accessible from your templates:

```
<!-- inside `home` template -->
{{controllers.application}}
```

See http://darthdeus.github.com/blog/2013/01/27/controllers-needs-explained/ for more detail on controller-needs.

BTW: It's pretty rare for an ember controller to use a custom init fx. Consider moving any initialization logic to `setupController` hook on the route instead.

Comment: Oct 2013: I had to use `this.get('controllers.application')` as opposed to `controllers.application`.

Answer (score -1):

```
App.HomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  init: function () {
    var applicationController = this.controllerFor('application');
  }
});
```

Comment: controllerFor is deprecated in 1.0.0.rc1 .. Rather use the needs mechanism described in Michael Grassotti's answer.